# this code has to find whether the given year is leap year or not . my code is incomple. i also need to know why i cant use (else) continously

Tags: python

help me with this project....

conditions for leap year :

on every year that is evenly divisible by 4

**except** every year that is evenly divisible by 100

**unless** the year is also evenly divisible by 400

my code:

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))

if year % 4 == 0 :
   
elif year % 100 !=0 :
    
elif year % 400 == 0 :

 print(f'the year {year} is a leap year')

else :
    print (f'{year} is not a leap year')
```

this need to tell whether a given year is a leap year r not

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to format your code by enclosing it in triple backquote \`\`\`your code \`\`\`. You also need to clearly formulate one question.

Comment: this is a duplicate, so i have voted to close.  as per @YevhenKuzmovych

Answer (score 2):

You're using if and elif statements wrong. The elif is only reached if the if condition is wrong. If you want to check all the conditions at once, you have to put them into the same line:

```
if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year %400 == 0):
    print (f'{year} is a leap year')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have some code between 'if' and 'elif' or combine conditions in first 'if' using 'and'. So the right code will be like this:

```
if year % 400 == 0:
    print(f"{year} is a leap year")
elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
    print(f"{year} is a leap year")
else:
    print(f"{year} is not a leap year")
```